# set model attribute based on request.user

Tags: django-rest-framework

Given a model like:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ...
```

I can use backend filters (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering) to only show the ones that belong to a user in a view.

```
class SomethingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Something.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (OwnedByUserBackend,) # Assume this filters by request.user
```

If I want to create a `Something` resource, is there a way to automatically set its `user` attribute to `request.user` using something that does the opposite of a filter (i.e. sets the attribute instead of filtering by it)?

Answer (score 1):

simply add a `perform_create` to your existing ViewSet class

```
class SomethingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

check [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) for more info